# Setting content of a textarea with innerHTML from an onclick event only works once

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to update the content of a `<textarea>` field when a `<button>` is clicked with the `onclick=""` event.

My problem is that the button only works once. If I change the content of the text area the button doesn't work anymore.

I've found several questions with the same problem but they all use variable inputs or not random data.

You can see an example here:

1. Click on the *Add test data* button
2. Modify the content of the textarea
3. Repeat step 1.: The button doesn't work but the console register the *done* message

```html
<script>
  function addExample() {
    document.getElementById('fasta').innerHTML = 'acgt';
    console.log('done');
  }
</script>
<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="addExample();">Add test data</button>
</p>

<textarea name="fasta" id="fasta"></textarea>
```

I'm using Firefox 44.0 on Ubuntu 15.04.

PS: I've found several questions with the same problem on Stack Overflow but they all use variable inputs or not random data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use innerHTML but the value property.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there a reason `innerHTML` only works once?

Comment: No, i dont know it, but i think, because it is a input, it is planned to be accessed via the value property in general. Consider marking my answer as accepted?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried to accept your answer but there is a grace period of 15 minutes before anyone can accept an answer. I'll do it later.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, i didnt know that.